# What is autoresizesForKeyboard and how does it work?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, autoresize

I was trying to find a way to adjust my screen when keyboard slides up so that the text field being edited (UITextView in my case) slides up and stays in focus instead of getting hidden behind the keyboard.

I saw a few discussion on google groups mentioning - autoresizesForKeyboard - 
http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/38bdadc89a1f35f8/2f8b92a6058cf136?lnk=raot&pli=1

I was not able to figure out how to use it or find any documentation for it.

Then I saw how Apple recommends to do it -
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html

However autoresizesForKeyboard sounds too intriguingly simple. Can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

autoresizesForKeyboard is part of the Three20 library and is a property of the TTViewController class.

http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_view_controller.html#acc0ff2c5d115eb977aaac419cb64f62b

"Three20 is an iPhone development library. It's the code that powers the Facebook iPhone app and many other apps in the app store."

http://three20.info/

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer. Will probably go apple way in this case :) Surprisingly never heard about three20 ... but am intrigued to check out the api ... looks like it could save a lot of development time for some specific tasks.